# Vectorial menu is empty

Tags: qgis

The "Vectorial" menu by qgis is empty. I need the data management tools. How can I make it appear?
I tried reinstalling Qgis 3.4.10, and nothing changed.

Comment: Check if the processing plugin is enabled. You can find it in pluginmanager.

Comment: Next to the vector menu, do you have the Processing menu?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to Plugins -> Manage and install Plugins.. -> Go to the tab "Installed" and enable the `Processing` core plugin.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.